# Unable to access "VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.10_93012"

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in Virtual Box and everything went well until i upgraded it recently to Ubuntu 14.04. After the upgrade, it is not entering into full screen and if i try to install "Virtual box additions" inside Ubuntu, it is showing Unable to access "VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.10_93012" as in the screenshot attached,

[image]

I think VBOXADDITIONS got corrupted somehow. Please guide me experts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you upgraded your VM, I'd suggest to update the Guest additions with the VM package manager in order to get their up-to-date versions.

Login first into your VM and open a Terminal to type:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Finally restart the VM to complete the installation.

Now you can safely detach the old guest additions ISO from your VM.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me when the guest add-on failed to mount.